# strange Java org.ini4j.Ini behaviour - file is edited without intentional edit

Tags: java, ini

I am having an ini file, which is my coniguration for a Java application.

I am using org.ini4j.Ini for the purpose of reading and editing the file.

```
ini = new Ini(new File("config.ini"));

[...]

public static String getImagePath() {
        return ini.get("other", "imagePath");
}
```

After starting the application and after executing the getImagePath function somehow Java or any program changes the config to

from

`imagePath = C:\tmp`

to

`imagePath = C: mp`

I don't see any code in my application doing this. The behaviour is reproducable.
I am using Process Monitor (ProcMon) to log all access on the file, but I can't find anything suspicious.
I also changed the machine and directory and the 'position of the variable in the configuration' without change. Could it be that a firewall or antivirus is causing this?

Comment: `\t` is also the character sequence for tab. can you change it to `C:\\tmp`?

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, I was specifying the imagePath as it is:

```
C:\tmp

 not C:\\tmp
```

and somehow java was after editing the configuration saving the file and interprets \t as tabulator.

Comment: You can mark your answer ad accepted